# Defining a struct with file scope to be accessed by multiple functions

Tags: c, function, data-structures, struct, scope

I have two functions.
1. Defines the data structure based on the inputs.
2. Uses the defined structure.

How can I define the structure in one function, and be able to use it in another function later?

```
 struct myStruct{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
     };

 void initialize(int size){
     struct myStruct myArray[size];
 }

 void operations(){
      myArray[1].a = 7;
 }
```

These are defined in an external file, and the inputs and outputs are set and shouldn't be changed. Is there a way to make my array of structs accessible later by a different function?

EDIT: Attempting to assign this to a pointer.

```
struct myStruct{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
     };
 struct cache_entry *p;
 void initialize(int size){
     struct myStruct myArray[size];
     *p = &myArray;
 }

 void operations(){
      myArray[1].a = 7;
 }
```

Comment: You can't.  Define the struct type outside the function(s).

Comment: I tried to use a pointer defined outside the function. For example: struct myStruct *p; then inside of initialize I tried to assign myArray to it, but it isn't working.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - that isn't desirable. The inputs are defined at run time and it's cleanest to keep initialization separate.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If you want to use a *type* in multiple places, you need to define that type in a place that can be seen by those multiple places.  That place is outside the functions.

Comment: On a second reading of your question, it's also not clear if you're talking about trouble defining a *type*, or a *variable*, or both.  Please clarify.

Comment: How can you expect the `operations` function to be able to know anything about `myArray` anyway? `myArray` isn't known to that function, at all.

Comment: Just the single variable. My code above is actually incorrect, sorry. The type is already defined outside of the function. I want to define the variable inside the function. I'll edit it.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin - this is why I'm asking. Surely I can assign a pointer to myArray to then access it within operations. I'm just unsure how to do so.

Comment: @BrandonSmith Nope, you can't do that either... As a local variable, `myArray` will just die when it reaches that `}` after its declaration. Thanks for the latest edit, though...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Then can I mem copy it into a predefined "global" variable outside of the function? The issue is that only the function knows the size it will be.

Comment: @BrandonSmith Yes you can, but you probably want to store the size in a global too.

Comment: "I tried to use a pointer defined outside the function" - can you construct a short program which shows this not working, so we can perhaps help you fix it?

Comment: @Dukeling edited above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, followed by your last edit, here's a suggestion you could make use of, hopefully:

Either declare a global pointer, that is to hold the address of a dynamically allocated memory location for your array of structures; or better make it with a local variable, by making the `initialize` function return the address of the dynamically allocated memory, also making the function `operations` to receive a pointer for your structure.

```
// Suggestion #1

struct myStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} * myArray;

void initialize( int size ) {
    myArray = malloc( size * sizeof * myArray );
}

void operations( ) {
    myArray[1].a = 7;
}


// Suggestion #2
// DO NOT USE THEM BOTH TOGETHER

struct myStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct myStruct * initialize( int size ) {
    return malloc( size * sizeof( struct myStruct ) );
}

void operations( struct myStruct * myArray ) {
    myArray[1].a = 7;
}
```

There you go, something like this. I hope I haven't made a mistake there.

Comment: Should that be myArray = malloc(size * sizeof(struct myStruct))?

Comment: @BrandonSmith Since `myArray` is defined as `struct myStruct * myArray;`, the following is true: `sizeof( struct myStruct ) == sizeof * myArray;`, therefore, the answer is: *It can be, both* and arguably my version is less error-prone.

Comment: I can't access elements this way. myArray[1].a = 7; isn't storing anything.

Comment: @BrandonSmith With suggestion #1: http://ideone.com/lrPZQK **~** With suggestion #2: http://ideone.com/dBuipF

Comment: Pardon me, for the second suggestion, I had a missing semicolon `;` and the `sizeof * myArray` part should be `sizeof( struct myStruct )`, since there is just no `myArray` there... I'll edit that now.